# How can I place ad code after every 5 activities in BuddyPress activity loop?

Tags: buddypress

I tried to display ad code in BuddyPress every 5 activities. Can anyone suggest  how this can be done? Here is what I've got so far:

```
<?php while ( bp_activities() ) : bp_the_activity(); ?>     

    <?php bp_get_template_part( 'activity/entry' );   ?>    

    <?php 

         $count = bp_get_activity_count(); 
         for ( $i = 1; $i < $count; $i++ ) {            
        if ( $i % 8 == 0 ) {                        

    ?>       

        <?php the_ad(3860); ?>

    <?php   } ?>        

    <?php } ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's where I would start:

```
<?php $count = 0; ?>
<?php while ( bp_activities() ) : bp_the_activity();?>
  <?php
    bp_get_template_part( 'activity/entry' );
    $count++;
    if ( $count % 5 == 0 ) {
      the_ad(3860);
    }
  ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```